# git branch --no-merged <list of branches>

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I've got 2 main branches `master` & `archive`. If some work was put on hold and I might need this in the future I archive that work by merging into `archive` branch. Labeling of unfinished work which needs to be kept is not an option for me because of some issues with labeling.

I wanna find out the branches which are not merged in any of the 2 branches(branch1 & branch2). I would like to run something like

```
git branch -a --no-merged branch1 branch2
```

When I run this way it kind'a works but the result is not what I need. I know one branch which was not merged in any of those 2 branches and it doesn't return me anything at all. When I start playing with some other 2 branches it returns some results.

A more detailed example

```
FC-o-o(b3)-o-o(b1)
  \         /
   o-o-o(b4)
   |\
   | o-o(b6)-o-o-o(b2)
   |  \       /
   |   o-o(b7)
   |     
   o-o(b5)             

FC - first commit
o - a commit
o(bN) - a branchN(one of the branch1,...,branch7) at a certain commit
```

So, if I run statement

```
git branch -a --no-merged branch1 branch2
```

I wanted to get one single branch5, because it was not merged in a any of the 2 branches branch1 and branch2. Please note I have not found anything in documentation what should happen when I specify 2 branches after --no-merged. It is just what I have tried to run to check if this will give me what I expect.

branch3, branch4, branch6 and branch7 are not in the output because

- branch3 changes are in branch1
- branch4 was merged into branch1
- branch6 changes are in the branch2
- branch7 was merged into branch2

Comment: Let's say you had 10 branches, including `branch1` and `branch2`.  Show us the branches which are in the output, explain why they are there?  Your logic is not clear to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question with the example which uses 7 branches. This should be enough

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler way to do this, but I have found none last time I checked, so I came up with this piece of script. It's formatted as 'alias' to be put into gitconfig file. If you're not interested in that, remove the obvious alias prefix, and the '!' at beginning and && true at the end of it.

```
[alias]
    unmer-excl = !git rev-list --all --no-merges --not `git rev-parse HEAD` $* | xargs -L1 git name-rev | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{40}\\s[^\\~\\^]*' | grep -vE '\\stags/' && true
```

The name of it stands for "**git unmer**ged-**excl**usive".

If added to aliases, this command works like this:

```
git unmer-excl
# ^ give me all not yet merged into current branch
111111 feature1
444444 feature1
222222 remotes/origin/experiment2
555555 remotes/origin/infrastructure
888888 remotes/origin/experiment2
333333 feature1
999999 remotes/origin/experiment2
```

as you see, this command lists **commits** along with their single best-**guessed** branch name. You can add branches to exclude:

```
git unmer-excl feature1 origin/experiment2
# ^ ...excluding anything that was already merged into feature1 or experiment2
555555 remotes/origin/infrastructure
```

This excludes not only fresh content on given branches, but everything that was already merged into that branch.

Output is listed in-order, from the most-recent commit to the oldest one. This is why it usually looks ugly if you're not used to it, but the advantages are:

- most recent first!
- shows commits, so you see "how much work" is pending to merge (few lines of commit IDs? fifteen screens?)
- simple output, easy to cut `| cut -d' ' -f2 | sort | uniq` and you get list of unmerged branches

  git unmer-excl | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort | uniq
  feature1
  remotes/origin/experiment2
  remotes/origin/infrastructure

As for the latter, you can even add it before && true to the alias, I didn't want to it by default, as it doing it that simple damages sorting by most-recent and uses simple name sorting instead.

For your original example:

```
FC-01-02(b3)-03-04(b1)
  \            /
   05-06-07(b4)
   |\
   | 08-09(b6)-10-11-12(b2)
   |   \         /
   |    13-14(b7)
   |     
   15-16(b5)
```

I changed `o` with commit numbers for better identification.
Examples below may differ in their output in terms of item ordering and branch names (is commit #14 could be labelled as B2 or B4, etc)

```
git checkout (somewhere not on B5)
git unmer-excl b1 b2    | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort | uniq
b5

git checkout b4
git unmer-excl          | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort | uniq
b1
b2
b5

git checkout FC
git unmer-excl b1 b2
15 b5
16 b5

git checkout b6
git unmer-excl b3 b4
03 b1
04 b1
10 b2
11 b2
12 b2
13 b2
14 b2
15 b5
16 b5
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you very much. It look what I was looking. I will check it out today.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know does it help for you, but also you can try to show diff of commits from branch1 and branch2 by command: `git log branch1..branch2`.

Comment: This is not what I wanted to find. I wanted to find an unfinished/unmerged work into 2 main branches.